# Group in nested join with "Filter" by Date

Tags: sql, t-sql

I need to make a self join on an invoice table, which I know how to do in general, but:
If Invoices in the past share an order number with the current invoice, I want to substract them from the current invoice. Therefore I need to group the older Invoices in the Join-statement. I have lots of columns and a complex Query, so I don't want to make another grouping outside the join. This is what I have regarding the self-join:

```
SELECT Invoice_Number
       ,Invoice_Date
       ,PO_Number
       ,Amount_Invoice
       ,Amount_PastInvoices

FROM Invoices

LEFT OUTER JOIN (
                 SELECT SUM(Amount_Invoice) as Amount_PastInvoices
                        ,PO_Number
                 FROM Invoices             
                 GROUP BY PO_Number


) Past_Invoices ON Invoices.PO_Number = Past_Invoices.PO_Number
```

This query will give me all the invoices for the specific ordner number, including the invoice iself. Somehow I have to put a `WHERE Past_Ivoices.Invoice_Date < Invoices.Invoice_date`, but I can't figure out how, because the join is grouped. Cann I pass the date to the nested join somehow, or are there other statements I could use?

I tried working with a sub-query, but then I needed to group outside of the "join" again.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like you can just use a window function to calculate a running total:

```sql
SELECT
  i.Invoice_Number
  i.Invoice_Date
  i.PO_Number
  i.Amount_Invoice
  Amount_PastInvoices = SUM(i.Amount_Invoice) OVER
          (PARTITION BY i.PO_Number ORDER BY i.Invoice_Date ROWS UNBOUNDED PRECEDING)
          - i.Amount_Invoice
FROM Invoices i;
```

You could also use

```sql
  Amount_PastInvoices = SUM(i.Amount_Invoice) OVER
          (PARTITION BY i.PO_Number ORDER BY i.Invoice_Date
           ROWS BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND 1 PRECEDING)
```

but I believe this is less efficient.

---

If you really wanted to use an inefficient self-join, you can use an `OUTER APPLY`. Note that this will return `NULL` if there are no rows.

```sql
OUTER APPLY (
    SELECT
      Amount_PastInvoices = SUM(Past_Invoices.Amount_Invoice)
    FROM Invoices Past_Invoices
    WHERE Past_Invoices.PO_Number = Invoices.PO_Number
      AND Past_Ivoices.Invoice_Date < Invoices.Invoice_date
) Past_Invoices
```